# how to plot xtick on the x-axis (y=0) tikz latex

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have the following graph

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

% example data file
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{datafile.dat}
thread speedup dev
1 1 0
2 3 1
3 5 0
4 7 1
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xlabel=threads,
    ylabel=speedup \& deviation,
    xtick={1,...,4}]

\addplot table[x=thread,y=speedup] {datafile.dat};
\addplot table[x=thread,y=dev] {datafile.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

As you can see I would the x ticks to be located on the x-axis (y=0) and I would also like to remove the box?
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add to your `axis` options:

```
axis x line = middle,
axis y line = left,
enlarge x limits,
enlarge y limits,
```

you will obtain

[image: result]

which is what I think you are looking for.